# Check if stored procedure modifies table data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am granting a user group permissions to execute all stored procedures in a database which contain the word "Report" or "PDF", on the condition that the execution of these stored procedures will not modify the data in the database.

Now, I am currently reading through each of these stored procedures one at a time and basically doing a code review on each of them with the intention of determining if they modify data, or if they simply retrieve data.

Is there a programmatic way to test for the modification of the database in a single-run procedure that only gets run when the programmers want it run?

Comment: You could probably get a pretty loose subset (with potential false positives) parsing sys.sql_modules for definition like update or insert or delete or merge. But an added complication is if any of those procedures call _other procedures_ or generate commands with dynamic SQL.

Comment: You would use some queries to help identify which procedures would require you to manually look closer. Things like insert, update, delete, exec, create, alter, there are many possibilities. Ideally you should move report procedures to a different schema. Then it becomes easy to deal with permissions like you are trying to.

Comment: @SeanLange the problem with that is that there are a lot of SP that are declaring and using temporary tables. And when I say a lot, I really mean a lot. half of the ones I've greenlit have used an `@declare` table in them. 

I know how to create a temp table for the procedures and grant execute. It's checking for modifications to the database that is the difficult part

Comment: @AaronBertrand check the response to Sean Lange above

Comment: Well then you are stuck going through those manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this information from the `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities` system function. `is_updated` will be `1` when any table is inserted, updated or deleted.

```sql
SELECT
  schema_name = s.name,
  p.name,
  is_updated = CAST(
      CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities(QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(p.name), 'OBJECT') r
        WHERE r.is_updated = 1)
      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    AS bit)
FROM sys.procedures p
JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = p.schema_id
WHERE (p.name LIKE '%Report%' OR p.name LIKE '%PDF%')
  AND p.is_ms_shipped = 0;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=15771e9190127d5106a1bdf309c34dd5)

Comment: What about if it calls other procedures?

Comment: True, but that wasn't asked. It also doesn't tell you about DDL. But it covers almost all uses.

Comment: True it wasn't mentioned but most likely the OP didn't consider that.

Comment: Needing to include procedures or not this an excellent way to find stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for words like `INSERT`, `UPDATE`,`DELETE`... in the stored procedure code, here's an exmple of the query :

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%INSERT%'
    OR OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%UPDATE%'
```

Comment: Would also need to include delete, exec, create, alter, drop...